# Actionscript: Dealing with large blitmasks

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have 150 buttons, each is the width of the screen and about 1/10 the height, so the total list height is large.

I am using a blitmask to make it scroll smoothly, however, this crashes on a mobile device, and when viewing the profile I see memory usage is 115mb  just for the single class.

This on a iPad retina with the 2048x1536 screen.

How do people handle large objects which create large blitmasks?

I think my issue will be worse on even higher resolution screens.

Comment: 1. GPU acceleration via Stage3D. 2. Resource management.

Comment: Also 150 buttons taking 1/10 height would be 15 buttons per screen. These the rest don't always need to be rendered. Even if you render 17 (15 + 1 top and 1 bottom for transitioning), it's still way less than 160 buttons. I haven't used actionscript in over half a decade, but I remember [scrollRect](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect) helped with that on a basic level. Starling and other GPU accelerated with blitting might also support something similar

Comment: thanks. In the end I disabled blitmask, when I had a couple of classes loaded with blitmask memory was hitting 400mb+. So I figure that on an iPad I was creating a bitmap that was 100's of MB and this was causing more issues than the blitmask solved.